# P2p photoSharing app using IPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking, p2p

I want to build an iPhone app that can transfer photos from one iPhone to another using a p2p connection between the two phones.

I know how to code a basic iPhone app, but have no idea on how to do the `p2p connection`.

Referrals to any books or tuts that can help me do this would be great!

Comment: Do you mean bluetooth, local network, or internet transfer?

Comment: Then you probably will need to go through a server to transfer the data, as there are many firewall and other problems just connecting device-to-device (not to mention security risks). You could always upload the file to your server, confirm the other person has downloaded it, and then just delete the file from the server, programmatically

Comment: The application is to transfer big images(about 60mb) and maybe videos,I want to cut the costs so I believe a p2p connection will be better.I heard Skype transfers video through a p2p connection,any idea how they do it?

Comment: There is no direct API for this then, as far as I know.

Comment: Am willing to build it from scratch,any idea how Skype does this?

Comment: They don't, they go through their servers. I really wish You could enter chat so I could help you there.

Comment: Add me in Facebook a20x50@Facebook.com

Comment: For clarification, do you mean P2P as in having intermediate hops between mobile devices, or just one phone directly sending to one other? The former might be an expensive drain on every participant's data transfer allowance, I would have thought. My understanding of Skype is that they use genuine P2P for the voice/video part, since the volume of data they would have to handle in a client-server model would be prohibitive (search for 'skype p2p' here to find a post that covers this).

Answer (score 1):

Gamekit implements stuff like that http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1 but I'm not sure it's ok for your context.